# PowerShell - How to surround argumentcompleter auto-completed arguments (that contain spaces) with single quotes?

Tags: powershell, autocomplete, single-quotes

I'm doing a simple demo to illustrate the ArgumentCompleter attribute in a function, and this is the code I'm working with so far:

```
#Requires -Modules Hyper-V
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
function Get-VMNameTest
{
    param (
        [ArgumentCompleter({
            param ($Command, $Parameter, $WordToComplete, $CommandAst, $FakeBoundParams)
            $VmNameArg = (Get-VM).Name | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*$WordToComplete*"}
            *foreach ($vm in $VmNameArg)
            *{
            *    if ($vm -match '\s+')
            *    {
            *        "'" + $vm + "'"
            *    }
            *    else {$vm}
            *}
        })]
        [string[]]$Name
    )

    foreach ($vm in $Name)
    {
        Write-Output "VMName:  $vm"
    }
}
```

The `-Name` parameter will autocomplete any VM (name) that's found on the local computer. I added a foreach loop (indicated with *'s) to add single quotes around any VM names that contain spaces -- otherwise a VM name (that contains spaces) will show up without quotes on the command line.

When using `CTRL + SPACE` to see the autocomplete values, native cmdlets present the values (that contain spaces) *without* single quotes in the list, but as soon as you arrow-key over a value with spaces, it automatically adds the single quotes to the command line (in this case, it presents as a path using `.\` and a trailing `\`.  To illustrate:

```
PS C:\> Get-Item -Path '.\Program Files\'
$Recycle.Bin               System Volume Information
Documents and Settings     Users
Program Files              Windows
Program Files (x86)
ProgramData
```

("Program Files" is selected via arrow keys in this example).

This is how my code appears with the foreach loop - the single quotes appear in both the list and the command line:

```
PS C:\> Get-VMNameTest -Name 'Server Two'
ServerOne                  'Server Two'
```

Without the foreach loop, single quotes do not surround values with spaces (which is obviously problematic):

```
PS C:\> Get-VMNameTest -Name Server Two
ServerOne                  Server Two
```

I'm trying to remain consistent with the behavior of native cmdlets, so this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
PS C:\> Get-VMNameTest -Name 'Server Two'
ServerOne                  Server Two
```

Clearly there's a difference in how native (compiled) cmdlets behave and the logic that adds the single quotes (or adds path separators, escapes necessary characters, etc).  Although it's a minor cosmetic difference, I want to know if there's a better way to approach this.  How do the pros do it?

Comment: you would need to create instances of `CompletionResult` using this overload: `public CompletionResult(string completionText, string listItemText, CompletionResultType resultType, string 
toolTip);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're looking to display completion items *unquoted* but when an item is selected it should be quoted, if that's the case, then you can accomplish it using the [`CompletionResult(String, String, CompletionResultType, String)` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.completionresult.-ctor?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#system-management-automation-completionresult-ctor(system-string-system-string-system-management-automation-completionresulttype-system-string)):

```bash
function Test-Completion {
    param(
        [ArgumentCompleter({
            param (
                $Command,
                $Parameter,
                $WordToComplete,
                $CommandAst,
                $FakeBoundParams
            )

            # generate a list of items here for testing,
            # some can have spaces, others dont
            $list = 0..10 | ForEach-Object {
                if($_ % 2) {
                    return "Item $_"
                }

                "Item$_"
            }

            foreach($item in $list) {
                if($item -notlike "$wordToComplete*") {
                    continue
                }

                $completionText = $item
                # if this item has a space
                if($item -match '\s') {
                    $completionText = "'$item'"
                }

                [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new(
                    $completionText, $item,
                    [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResultType]::ParameterValue,
                    'some tooltip here if you want')
            }
        })]
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Test
    )

    $Test
}
```

Comment: Thanks Santiago - this works great.  I'd like to include a condition to add single quotes only if there are spaces in the autocomplete result (rather than adding single quotes to every result) - that keeps things consistent with PS cmdlet behavior.  Including an if block in the ForEach-Object block breaks the autocomplete for some reason that I haven't yet figure out.

Comment: that update should do it, its not that pretty tho @Paulπ

Comment: I'm such an idiot.  That's exactly what I was doing, only I had forgotten to comment out a duplicate completion result constructor above your working version - that's why my autocomplete results were of the local file system rather than VM names.  I shortened the constructor call by using ($completionText, $_, 8, $_) so it's actually not that bad.  Thank you again, Santiago!

Comment: @Paulπ np, glad it was helpful