# PowerShell 7 autocompletion adds .\ to the file name in the current folder... which is sometimes a problem

Tags: powershell, pdflatex, tab-completion

I use pdflatex from the PowerShell 7 terminal on Windows 11.

When I press "tab" to autocomplete the name of the file in the current folder, it adds `.\` at the begining (for example, I get `pdflatex .\filename.tex`), which pdflatex does not understand. Hence, I have to move the cursor, remove the `.\` at the begining, and then press enter, which is not very confortable since the idea of using tab in the first pleace is to write less. What can I do?

I am using PowerShell 7.4.1 and pdflatex 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (Tex Live 2023) with kpathsea version 6.3.5.

Step by step to reproduce the problem.

- Write `pdflatex fil` in the terminal
- Press <Tab>
- get `pdflatex .\filename.tex` instead of the expected `pdflatex filename.tex`
- press <Enter>
- get the following error from pdflatex:

```
> pdflatex .\filename.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> .\filename
          .tex
?
```

Comment: I assume you want completion of the items in the current location right?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you're looking for completion of `.tex` files in the current location without the `.\` in which case you can use [`Register-ArgumentCompleter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter?view=powershell-7.4) with the `-Native` switch:

```bash
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName pdflatex -Native -ScriptBlock {
    param($wordToComplete, $commandAst, $cursorPosition)

    Get-ChildItem -Filter *.tex |
        Where-Object { $_.Name.StartsWith($wordToComplete, [StringComparison]::InvariantCulture) } |
        ForEach-Object Name
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I come from bash... I have to learn this language :-)

Comment: @AlejandroDC glad it was helpful :) note that the completion items can be transformed, i.e.: list item completion shows the files name and when selected it transforms to their fullname (absolute path), you can also wrap the path with quotes, etc. here an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76478226/powershell-how-to-surround-argumentcompleter-auto-completed-arguments-that-co/76478279#76478279 can add to this answer if any doubts